# Which denominations dislike pictures of people?

Tags: denomination-survey, art

I remember this sect from the news, but I forgot the term. Does anyone know what I mean?

Aniconism isn't the answer (because I know this noun already) but also because this faction allows their apostles to take selfies and portraits **strictly on a necessary basis** like to fulfill banking, government, and travel requirements. They can take selfies for applying for a bank account, credit card, driver's license, and passports.

Their worshipers can use, but are forbidden to take selfies or portraits on, social media like Instagram. They can upload pictures of anything besides their own faces.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Amish, I believe, but they're not apt to answer for themselves here!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Amish and Old Order Mennonites](https://www.discoverlancaster.com/amish/photographs/) disapprove of pictures of people. Stricter orders will not have family photos, and some, if you try to take a picture of them going about their business, will turn away from the camera in order to not have their faces showing.

> The Amish hold humility as a highly-cherished value and view pride as a threat to community harmony. Because items such as personal photographs can accentuate individuality and call attention to one's self, they are prohibited from the home. Moreover, the Amish believe that photographs in which they can be recognized violate the Biblical commandment, "Thou shalt not make unto thyself a graven image." They want to be remembered by the lives they lived and the examples they left, not by physical appearance.